# select SQL troubles

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
    select a.class_id, b.std_id, 
    ( select count(*) from enrollment where class_id = a.class_id ) as class_size, 
    d.admission_id 
    from class a, student b, enrollment c, admission d
    where
    c.class_id = a.class_id and
    c.std_id = d.std_id and
    c.std_id = b.std_id
    order by a.class_id;
```

The result is:

```
class_id std_id class_size 
comp100 8080 4 
comp100 8020 4 
comp100 8033 4 
comp100 8111 4 
comp305 8080 4 
comp305 8080 4 
comp305 8020 4 
comp305 8033 4 
comp555 8111 1 
comp672 8080 3 
comp672 8033 3 
comp672 8111 3
```

But I just want to display one of the results if the class size is more than 1

that is

I would like to do so:

```
class_id std_id class_size 
comp100 8080 4 
comp305 8080 4 
comp555 8111 1 
comp672 8080 3
```

After thinking a while, I should get the counter first, like this

```
select enrollment.class_id, count(*) as class_size 
from class, enrollment
where enrollment.class_id = class.class_id
group by enrollment.class_id;
```

then the counter is retrieved as follows:

```
class_id class_size
comp100 4
comp305 4
comp555 1
comp672 3
```

however, I don't know how to use one SQL statement to realize the result.

I would like to ask for your advice, how to modify the SQL statement so that I can show only one of the rows if the class size is more than 1.

that is, if the class size is 4, i do not want to show 4 results, instead, i result is enough.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: is this homework? Your anonymous username also suggests it, not to mention the nature of the query (these teachers are pretty predictable too).

Comment: I use oracle oracle sql plus, and this is a question raised when working.

Comment: Think about that 'where' part.  You want more conditions there to limit thre results.  Read up on SQL to see how to do WHERE's.  It's very basic.

Comment: btw change that where statement to a JOIN statement (again research JOIN's) and use the WHERE for real where's

Comment: Is this homework? I've seen too many questions similar to this with these tables. If so, play fair and tag it as such,

Comment: You need to decide on what the business logic is for **which** row you want returned when you "only want one row". If you want a student ID returned (I'm not sure why you would and why your second resultset isn't sufficient) then you need to decide what logic determines which student ID is returned. Once you understand your requirements *then* you can go about coding to accomplish them.

Comment: So, from your question I understand that you need class_id, any random std_id and number of students. Then why do you join it with admission table? Anyway, you could try to use `row_number()` feature. Description could be found [there](http://www.bikinfo.com/HTML/TD/TD_vs_Oracle.html#_Toc_Qualify).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the prettiest query, but it should get you what you are asking for:

```
select distinct class_id, std_id, class_size
from (
    select a.class_id, b.std_id, 
        ( select count(*) from enrollment where class_id = a.class_id ) as class_size, 
        d.admission_id 
    from class a, student b, enrollment c, admission d
    where
        c.class_id = a.class_id and
        c.std_id = d.std_id and
        c.std_id = b.std_id) subquery1
where
    subquery1.class_size > 1

union all

select class_id, std_id, class_size
from (
    select a.class_id, b.std_id, 
        ( select count(*) from enrollment where class_id = a.class_id ) as class_size, 
        d.admission_id 
    from class a, student b, enrollment c, admission d
    where
        c.class_id = a.class_id and
        c.std_id = d.std_id and
        c.std_id = b.std_id) subquery2
where
    subquery2.class_size = 1

order by class_id
```